# bar plot with ggplot dor one group of variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm tyring to make a bar chart with ggplot and I need to show just one category from the column "Having trip".

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(combo_n, aes(x=N_Trips,fill = 'Have Trip')) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = ((..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..])),color="blue", fill="white") +
    facet_grid(REFYEARP~REFMTHP)+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8, angle = 90))+
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=-Inf)) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=-Inf)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format())+
    labs(title = "Month", y = "Percent", x = "Having trip or Not")+
    coord_cartesian(clip="off")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! What are you trying to achieve? Can you share your data (with `dput()` (or create a similar dataset) so that we can help?

Comment: You need to apply a filter before `ggplot`